# Is it possible to run tear down fixture only after all params runs?

Tags: python, pytest, finalizer, fixture, teardown

For instance if you have:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('lang',
                         ["EN",
                          "FR"])
def test_whats_hot_quick_links_are_displayed(self, lang):
       # Do something here
```

and i have this teardown fixture in conftest:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def teardown_function(request):    
    def execute_at_the_end():
        logging.info("Ending Test Case...")   
        database.clear()

    request.addfinalizer(execute_at_the_end)
```

So how can i make the teardown function execute only after both EN and FR test runs are executed instead of having this run after each param run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this behaviour I use `scope=class` and wraps my test with `class`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='class')
def teardown_after_all_params():
    yield
    execute_at_the_end()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('teardown_after_all_params')
class TestLinks:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('lang', ["EN", "FR"])
    def test_whats_hot_quick_links_are_displayed(self, lang):
        # Do something here
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated